# Eigenvalues and inverse of matrix which has matrix entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a $2\times2$ matrix which contains $2\times2$ matrices as entries, is there a clean way to find the inverse of such object and compute its eigenvalues/vectors?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion for the inversion of a blockwise-matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R:=\mathbb R^{2,2}$ the ring of $2x2$ matrices. This ring is not commutative, which complicates everything.

Take a matrix $A=\pmatrix{a_{11}& a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}} \in R^{2,2}$.

Assume that:

1. $a_{11}a_{22}= a_{22}a_{11}$
2. $a_{12}a_{21} = a_{21}a_{12}$
3. $\det(A):= a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21}$ is invertible

then $A$ is invertible and
$$
A^{-1} = (\det A)^{-1} \pmatrix{a_{22}& -a_{12}\\-a_{21}&a_{11}}.
$$
This can be checked similarly to the case of a $\mathbb R^{2,2}$ matrix.

This approach works for the permutation matrix
$$
P=\left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right)
$$
as the diagonal and off-diagonal entries commute. and $\det A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the inverse of a 2x2 block matrix
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21}&A_{22}
\end{array}\right)$$
is (just like a normal 2x2 matrix)
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \left(\begin{array}{cc} A_{22} & -A_{12}\\ -A_{21}&A_{11}
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: But now $\det(A)\in \mathbb R^{2,2}$

Comment: No det(A) is a real number, just the determinant of a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Then the claim is not true, see this matrix $P=\left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right)$ which is a permutation matrix, so its inverse is a permutation matrix as well

Answer (score 0):

A $2 \times 2$ matrix whose entries are $2 \times 2$ matrices themselves is exactly the same thing as a $4 \times 4$ matrix, so you can use any of the usual matrix techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrices $A_{11},\;A_{12},\;A_{21},\;A_{22}$ do not have any special properties, then there is nothing that makes $A$ special compared to any other $4\times 4$ matrix. Therefore, as quarague already mentioned, you can use any of the usual matrix techniques.

If the blocks have special properties, then it may be possible to simplify the inversion and eigenvalue/eigenvector calculation.

One thing that comes to my mind is the commutative property. If $A_{11},\;A_{12},\;A_{21},\;A_{22}$ all commute, you get
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix} (A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & (A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})^{-1} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A_{22} & -A_{12} \\ -A_{21} & A_{11} \end{pmatrix}
$$